# Changing images through admin panel

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hey stackoverflow users,

I'm curious about Wordpress, I'm new to the whole Wordpress theme creation so I've began by using the basics of HTML combined with looking through the Wordpress codex to build a theme.

However, I have one question: How could I make it so images could be changed through the admin panel?

Let's look at it like this, I could set out, say; a logo div and a banner div, is there a way I could be able to set them so their images could be modified through the panel?

What would be the easiest method to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following for the header image:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Custom_Header

You can also define custom text inputs via the Settings API:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

I would say that the second link is not for beginners. To gain a little familiarity with theming I would try deconstructing Twenty Twelve or Twenty Thirteen. I would also examine the reason why you want to content manage these particular items. If you are looking to create a theme for distribution, there are many resources that can help you with this in the WordPress Codex.

Answer (score -1):

there is no simple way to do that, you would first code or modify a theme to make it work like  plugin, or what would i suggest is use theme editor in admin panel that is possible easiest way available.